# Te form of もっていく

Tags: verbs, conjugations, て-form

Quick question regarding the -te form of the verb もっていく (to take). From my understanding the verb is a combination between もって+ いく(to go) and as such conjugates its -te form as もっていって is this correct?

The reason I'm asking is because I've seen it conjugated online a few times as もっていいて which would indicate that the -te form would be conjugating as if it were a regular -く ending verb, as opposed to conjugating as いく (to go) does (いって）.

If someone could clarify it's conjugation I'd be super appreciative.

Thanks!

Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about a website like [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F)?

It appears that some sites which automatically generate conjugation charts treat "もっていく" as though it's a regular godan verb, but you're correct that it's もって + いく, and that いく conjugates as it normally does.

It should be [もっていって](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1W%BB%FD%A4%C3%A4%C6%A4%A4%A4%AF_v5k-s), not *もっていいて.

Comment: Yes exactly, thank you very much for clarifying!